# How to make a conditional that uses existing modifier value if present and adds one if not present

Tags: scripting

So how would i script an operator to ignore a bevel that is on the object but add a bevel if it is already on the object. But also if a bevel is there to keep that width value instead of modifying it.

```
class csharpenOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
'''Sharpen With Modifiers and Bevelling'''
bl_idname = "csharpen.objects"
bl_label = "CSharpen"
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'} 

items = [(x.identifier, x.name, x.description, x.icon) 
         for x in bpy.types.Modifier.bl_rna.properties['type'].enum_items]

modtypes = EnumProperty(name="Modifier Types",
                       items=[(id, name, desc, icon, 2**i) for i, (id, name, desc, icon) in enumerate(items)
                               if id in ['BOOLEAN', 'MIRROR', 'BEVEL', 'SOLIDIFY']],
                       description="Don't apply these",
                       default={'BEVEL'},
                       options={'ENUM_FLAG'})

angle = FloatProperty(name="AutoSmooth Angle",
                      description="Set AutoSmooth angle",
                      default= radians(60.0),
                      min = 0.0,
                      max = radians(180.0),
                      subtype='ANGLE')

bevelwidth = FloatProperty(name="Bevel Width Amount",
                           description="Set Bevel Width",
                           default=0.0200,
                           min =
                           0.002,
                           max =0.25)

apply_all = BoolProperty(default = True)

original_bevel = FloatProperty()

@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    ob = context.object
    if ob is None:
        return False
    return (ob.type == 'MESH')

    #F6 MENU
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    box = layout.box()
    # DRAW YOUR PROPERTIES IN A BOX
    #box.prop( self, 'ssharpangle', text = "SsharpAngle")
    col = box.column()
    col.prop(self, "modtypes", expand=True)
    box.prop( self, 'angle', text = "SmoothingAngle" )
    box.prop( self, 'bevelwidth', text = "BevelWidth")
    box.prop( self, 'apply_all', text = "ApplyAll")

def execute(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    ob = context.object  # soapbox call don't use bpy.context as context is passed
    obs = context.selected_objects
    angle = self.angle
    original_bevel = self.original_bevel
    bevelwidth = self.bevelwidth

    #Sets Original Bevel To Initial Value
    #original_bevel = 0.2
    original_bevel = bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].width

    #Just Trying To Make It Work
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Bevel")
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Solidify")
    #so that the csharp doesnt mesh up the object

    #keep the old here for now
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BEVEL')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].use_clamp_overlap = False
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].show_in_editmode = False
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].width = bevelwidth
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].segments = 3
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].profile = 0.70
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].limit_method = 'WEIGHT'

    mod_dic = {}
    if self.apply_all:
        #remove modifiers no one would want applied in this instance

        #bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Bevel")
        #bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Solidify")
        # replace with       
        mods = [m for m in ob.modifiers if m.type in self.modtypes]
        for mod in mods:

            mod_dic[mod.name] = {k:getattr(mod, k) for k in mod.bl_rna.properties.keys()
                                 if k not in ["rna_type"]}
            print(mod_dic)
            ob.modifiers.remove(mod)

        #convert to mesh for sanity
        #bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')            
        #Object.to_mesh(scene, apply_modifiers, settings, calc_tessface=True, calc_undeformed=False)

        mesh_name = ob.data.name
        ob.data.name = 'XXXX'
        # remove the old mesh
        if not ob.data.users:
            bpy.data.meshes.remove(ob.data)               
        mesh = ob.to_mesh(scene, True, 'PREVIEW') # or 'RENDER'
        ob.modifiers.clear()
        mesh.name = mesh_name
        ob.data = mesh

        for name, settings in mod_dic.items():
            m = ob.modifiers.new(name, settings["type"])
            for s, v in settings.items():
                if s == "type":
                    continue
                setattr(m, s, v)

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

I think at some point I got confused as to how the script works which could be whats making it hard. But the expected behavior is always if a bevel isnt present then add one but now I have a 2nd operator that puts a bevel on the object just to allow this operator to work without error.

Comment: You should check for BEVEL type in your "for mod in mods" loop. Then you can add the new bevel mod after if your loop returns no bevel types.

Comment: The code  `ob = context.object` lets you  use ob as an object reference rather than  bpy.context.object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a modifier named "Bevel" exists and if not add one

```
obj = context.object
mod = obj.modifiers.get("Bevel") # returns None if not present

if mod is None:
    # add one
    mod = object.modifers.new("Bevel", 'BEVEL')

    mod.use_clamp_overlap = False
    mod.show_in_editmode = False
    mod.width = bevelwidth
    mod.segments = 3
    mod.profile = 0.70
    mod.limit_method = 'WEIGHT'
```

Note, get is used as

```
obj.modifiers["Bevel"]
```

will throw an error if there is no modifier named Bevel

I'd suggest using name apart from "Bevel", the default name for a bevel modifier if you are going to add a custom one.

To get all the BEVEL type modifiers, as suggested by Todd_McIntosh

```
mods = [m for m in ob.modifiers if m.type == 'BEVEL']
print(obj.name, "has", len(mods), " BEVEL modifiers")
for mod in mods:
    print(mod.name)
```

which was in the first incarnation of the answer [Why does bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH') have an error?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40482/why-does-bpy-ops-object-converttarget-mesh-have-an-error/40487#40487) and was changed to allow you to copy, remove, apply others then re-add, for more than just the BEVEL modifier

The same `collection.get(...)` and `collection.new(...)` or `collection.add(...)` works for most collections on blender. Use python console auto-complete <kbd>ctrl-space</kbd> to see what options are available.

```
>>> C.object.modifiers.new(
new()
ObjectModifiers.new(name, type)
Add a new modifier
>>> C.object.modifiers.new(
```

Comment: ah now im confused. So I guess i am falling behind on my understanding of the code since the dictionary was added. I think it has become more complicated than my understanding is capable of. So I would need to add this to the for loop? Is there a way to keep it simple where it does the normal operation however it just adds a bevel if not present?

Comment: It might be an idea to create a dedicated  post in http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?11-Python-Support , rather than adding a new question here pertaining to each new issue.

Comment: yeah youre right. I will try another mean for these issues because its just getting more and more complex and presenting new issues with each change. sorry about that!

Comment: Absolutely no problem at all, happy to help on BA.  Remember the print statement is your friend, for instance printing the dictionary will show it's just a quick way to store the modifier settings.  Coding is a J curve type of thing, a little perseverance and it will be worth it.